# My Tkinter button error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a `LagSwitch` using python `tkinter`, however I got a error that I'm unable to fix, I'm new to `tkinter`. Could you please help?

My error that I get running the script:

> ActivateButton = Button(text="Activate",fg="green", bg="black",command=activate)
>   NameError: name 'activate' is not defined

This is my script:

```
#MAIN
from tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()

#FRAMES
topFrame = Frame()
topFrame.pack(side=TOP)
bottomFrame = Frame()
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#LABELS
MainLabel = Label(text="LagSwitch V0.1", fg="green", bg="black", font="arial")
MainLabel.pack()

#BUTTONS
QuitButton = Button(text="Close", command=quit, fg="red", bg="black", font="arial")
QuitButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)
ActivateButton = Button(text="Activate", fg="green", bg="black", command=activate)
ActivateButton.pack(side=TOP)
DeActivateButton = Button(text="Deactivate", fg="red", bg="black", command=deactivate)
DeActivateButton.pack(side=TOP)

#Activate/Deactivate command
def activate():
    os.system("networksetup -setairportpower airport on")
def deactivate():
    os.system("networksetup -setairportpower airport off")

#ROOT STUFF
root.geometry("500x300")
root.configure(background="black")
root.title("LagSwitch V0.1")
root.mainloop()
```

What can I do? I'm a beginner so I'm not that smart. How can I improve the script and fix the error that I am having? I do not understand.

Comment: Im on a cellphone so i can't try. what happens if you move your activate and deactivate functions up above your buttons?

Comment: As the error states, `activate` is not yet defined when you use it in your button definition. You define `activate` only a few lines later. So, just move your `activate` and `deactivate` function definitions over your `#BUTTONS` section.

Comment: you have to define a function _before_ referencing it somewhere else in your code. This has nothing to do with tkinter, it's just how python works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to have a handler function, you need to declare it **before** you're using this function, like this:

```
def activate():
    os.system("networksetup -setairportpower airport on")

ActivateButton = Button(text="Activate", fg="green", bg="black", command=activate)
```

So you need to switch your sections `#Activate/Deactivate command` and `#BUTTONS` in script.

Comment: Thank you guys SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def printName(event):
    print("Hello my name is User")


button_1 = Button(root, text="Press Me")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", printName) 

root.mainloop()
```

Try bind the buttons like in my small example.

Comment: Note: print("Hello my name is User") should be indented./